# Python: Use a dictionary to output the mode of a text file

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a text file with an unknown amount of numbers included. My program reads in the values and calculates the minimum value, the maximum value, the range and the median. The last thing that I have to do is find the mode of the set.

I have a sorted list that I am iterating through with a loop in order to place all of the numbers in a dictionary where the key is the number and the value for each number is how many times the number occurs. I understand how to do all of that, but now I need to output the mode of the set.

```
num_count = {}

for num in num_list:
    if num in num_count:
        num_count[num] += 1
    if num not in num_count:
        num_count[num] = 1
```

The above code is what places all of the numbers in the dictionary from the list and gives them the corresponding value with how many times that number occurs in the file, so now I just need to output the mode in a fashion such as [mode_1, mode_2, mode_3, etc..], but I can only get one number to appear.

I have a text file where the mode should output as:

```
Mode: [660, 476]
```

However, the code I have outputs as:

```
Mode: 660
Mode: 476
```

This is what I have so far:

```
maximum = 0

for num in num_count:
    count = num_count[num]
    if count > maximum:
        maximum = count
    if count == maximum:
        print('Mode: ', num)
```

Using a dictionary seems like the easiest way to go about this. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Basic python loop would be best, without imported things like counter and such.

Comment: instead of `print`ing there add `num` to a temp list and then print it outside of the `for` loop

Comment: You might want to take a look at Counter and DefaultDict. https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html

Comment: Okay; so you collect the modes in a list; don't print until *after* the loop that finds modes.  Where are you stuck?  Note that "any help" is a strong signal that your question is not yet specific enough for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @depperm That makes sense, I don't know why I didn't catch that. I think I've been staring at it a little too long. The problem with my dictionary that I have encountered is that the key in the key:value pair is the number and the value is the amount of times each number occurs, and that is an unknown number how do i get those values and then transfer the corresponding keys to the temp_list?

Comment: `for key,val in num_count.items():`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a function `compute_mode` with a argument which takes in a list(in this case num_count). The function finds mode and stores them in a `temp_list` which is then printed out

Append all the mode values to a list like this:

```
temp_list.append(num)
```

Then print the list like this:

```
print("Mode: " ,temp_list)
```

Final code:

```
temp_list = []
def compute_mode(my_list):
    counts = {}
    maxcount = 0
    for number in my_list:
        if number not in counts:
            counts[number] = 0
        counts[number] += 1
        if counts[number] > maxcount:
            maxcount = counts[number]

    for number, count in counts.items():
        if count == maxcount:
            temp_list.append(number)

num_count = [1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,4] #any list
compute_mode(num_count)
print('Mode:', temp_list)
```

Comment: Thank you! In the text file, the mode should be [660, 476] because they occur twice while all other numbers occur once. When I run this code, I get [728, 44, 591, 660, 476] I know what is causing the problem, because it adds the first numbers to the list because they are the max until 660 shows up, but how do I get around that?

Comment: No, unfortunately. The output was a list of all the numbers that are in the text file, so basically a list of 40 numbers.

Comment: Oh, no, sorry. I have a num_list that I used to find the median, and I loop through that and put all of the numbers and values in a dict, num_count.

Comment: You need to input a list

Comment: Yeah, that's where I was messing up. It works now!! Appreciate all the help!

Comment: @Glad to help !

Answer (score 0):

Use a list

```
maximum = 0
modes = []

for num in num_count:
    count = num_count[num]
    if count > maximum:
        maximum = count
    if count == maximum:
        modes.append(num)

print('Mode: ', modes)
```

Comment: Thank you! In the text file, the mode should be [660, 476] because they occur twice while all other numbers occur once. When I run this code, I get [728, 44, 591, 660, 476] I know what is causing the problem, because it adds the first numbers to the list because they are the max until 660 shows up, but how do I get around that?

Comment: to get around that, you'll need to calculate the maximum before appending any numbers to your modes list. To do that just call max(num_count.values())

Answer (score 0):

- You can achieve that with the built-in module `collections`.
- Use `Counter` to count the occurrence of each element in the list and save it in a dictionay.
- Use `most_common(n)` function to give the most common `n` numbers in the dictionary.

  ```
  import collections
  from collections import Counter

   num_count = [1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,4]    
   count_dict = Counter(num_count)
   print(count_dict.most_common(1)[0])  # <--- you can change 1 to 2 or 3
  ```

**output:**

```
(4, 3)
```